# checking if an input of an integer is a string with try catch

Tags: java, try-catch

I want the try-catch to loop until i input a proper integer, but all i am having is an infinite loop when i enter a string :

```
public class Main00 {
static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
static int c = 1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num = 0;
    while (c == 1) {
        try {
            System.out.println("enter a number");
            num = scan.nextInt();
            c = 2;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("enter a Number please : ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: while(c==1) the cause for infinite loop..

Comment: Isn't that the point of the code?

Comment: @Sasha yes. but code does't reach the c=2.

Comment: can you please explain why its happening like this in question code

Comment: @CoderNeji: as long as the input is not a valid int, it will go to the catch block without running c = 2;, meaning c will never become 2. This is why the while-condition remains true. To me, it seems logical that if the application needs an int, you keep asking until you get one.

Comment: but it doesn't asks for an int for the second and further iterations... why ????

Comment: basically, the code still has the previous value of the int in memory, and considers that your input. one possible solution, is to instantiate the Scanner each iteration, and to close it after each nextInt() read (but this might cause overhead)

Comment: @Stultuske, while looking in this issue I learned you could also use scan.next() to avoid the problem of the previous value in memory!

Comment: @TomJonckheere: absolutely. but if you use next, you read it as next, you 'll need to parse it to an int. There 'll always be some additional work to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the loop with following:

```
while (c == 1) {
            try {
                System.out.println("enter a number");
                num = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
                c=2;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("enter a Number please : ");
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you please explain why its happening like this in question code

Comment: @CoderNeji  May be because, `scanner.nextInt()` doesn't skip the bad token(i.e. the non int value). On any exception it will reset the index to the buffer currently held by the Scanner to the start of the previous match. which is not the case with `nextLine()`

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
try {
        System.out.println("enter a number");
        num = scan.nextInt();
        c = 2;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        c = -1;
        System.out.println("best of luck next time :)");
}
```

Comment: can you please explain why its happening like this in question code

Comment: This answer would really benefit by including some explanation for OP instead of just providing code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class Main00 {
static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
static int c = 1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
int num = 0;
while (c == 1) {
    try {
        System.out.println("enter a number");
        String value = scan.nextLine();
        num = Integer.parseInt(value);
        c=2;
        break;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: goes for the next iteration.. neglecting the previous exception

Answer (score 0):

With minimum use of variables and neater, you really don't require `c` variable.

```
    int num = 0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter a number");
            num = Integer.parseInt(scan.next());
            break;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            continue;
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you please explain why its happening like this in question code

Comment: what do you need the continue; statement for?

Comment: Here is the algo --> 1. Enter a loop  2. prompt the user to enter some input 3.  if it is not a number then go to "2"  4. If it is a number break and continue further. "Continue" is to continue the loop again, and once requirement is met, break the loop and come out.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution without using an exception to validate the input and some other optimisations:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num;
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("enter a valid number");
        if(scan.hasNextInt()){
            num = scan.nextInt();
            break;
        }else{
            scan.next();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("input: " + num);
}
```

You just check if next value is an integer, and if it's an integer you put it directly in your `num` value. This has the benifit of not using the exception and not needing to parse the String to an integer. I also changed the while loop, now you don't need that `c` variable... It was just confusing ;-)